# PHP Mysql check endtime is less then 2.50 hour and update records

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table user and  campaign.

User table has fields as below

```
 id, data_limit
 1     50
 2     180
 3     180
```

Campaign table has fields as below

```
campaign_id, user_id, end_datetime
   1              1         2016-10-06 09:05:10
   2              1         2016-10-04 10:05:10
   3              2         2016-10-06 13:05:10
   4              2         0000-00-00 00:00:00
   5              3         2016-10-06 13:05:10
```

My requirement

Increase **data_limit** of user table to 200 when **end_datetime** in campaign table is less than 2.50 hours from current time.
Action must be perfomed on latest **end_datetime (DESC)**

In here example data, query has to check only end_datetime with value 2016-10-06 09:05:10 of user_id 1, becuase it is lastest end_datetime

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query:

```
update tbluser u, (select u.id from tbluser u1 left join campaigntbl c on c.user_id =u1.id 
group by c.user_id having ADDTIME(max(c.end_datetime), '2:30') < now() ) as tbl set u.data_limit = u.data_limit + 200 where  u.id=tbl.id
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group by c.user_id having ADDTIME(max(c.end_datetime), '2:30') < now()' at line 3

Comment: Now try this one.

Comment: Still there is error but I got idea to use max function.